# Auto layout NSWindow respects minimum size in IB simulator, but not when running for real

Tags: macos, interface-builder, autolayout, nswindow

I have a window I'm setting up with auto layout. There is a view in the middle of the window that contains three controls, and I would like the window to refuse to resize horizontally smaller than the intrinsic size of those three controls.

[image: Running in simulator]

The outer buttons both have horizontal space constraints to "stick" them to the outside of their superview, and the checkbox in the middle has a horizontal space constraint sticking it to the left side of the "Sync text" button. There is also a >= constraint between the "Sync outline" button and the checkbox, to make sure they don't overlap, but the checkbox prefers to hang to the right. All these constraints have a priority of 1000. The window itself has no minimum size specified.

When I use the "Simulate Document" command in Xcode, everything works as I'd expect, and the window won't let you size it smaller than in the screenshot above. However, when I run my application, the window does allow resizing smaller than that width, so that the buttons start to shrink and eventually the controls overlap each other. I'm not implementing any of the size related window delegate methods, so I don't see any place in the app's code where it might be influencing the resizing.

Any ideas on what could be causing this difference in behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally figured out what the heck was going on here. It turns out the problem was that I was implementing the `-splitView:constraintMinCoordinate:ofSubviewAt:` delegate method (as well as the maxCoordinate one) to restrict the size of the split subviews in the vertical direction. Yes, restricting the *vertical* resizing of the split view affected the *horizontal* layout of the buttons.

It appears that what happens is that, if you implement those delegate methods, NSSplitView reverts back to using autoresizing masks to layout the subviews rather than auto layout constraints. Since the view containing those buttons is no longer participating in auto layout, the buttons smush together when you resize the window small. In the simulator, the split view doesn't have a delegate set, so all the auto layout stuff works fine in that environment. Note that merely having the methods implemented is enough to trigger this, even if they just return the proposed coordinates unchanged.

The solution ended up being quite easy, which was to delete the delegate methods and replace it with a vertical constraint on the subview to restrict its size instead.